# Error while trying to Manage Contour levels?

Tags: matlab, octave, contourf

Here is a code simulating the Electric Potential around two oppositely charged particles:

```
clc; clear; close all;

e_0 = 8.987E-9;                             % Coulomb's constant
xy = [1,2.5; 4,2.5];                        % particle coordinates.
q = [1; -1];                                % particle charge.

sBeg = 0;
sStep = 0.1;
sEnd = 5;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(sBeg : sStep : sEnd);      % generate a 2D-coordinate grid 

V_E = zeros( size(X) );                     % initialise electric potential field.

for i = 1 : numel(q)                        % add potential fields of each charge

  V_E = V_E + e_0 * q(i) ./ hypot( xy(i,1 ) - X, xy(i, 2) - Y );

end

contourf(X,Y, V_E);
ylabel( colorbar, 'Electric Potenial (V)' )
```

Result:

[image]

The contours are concentrated densely near the positions of the particles, how to "spread them" more evenly, while maintaining the same scale for the axis?

NB:

I've tried:

```
hc = contourf(X,Y,V_E);

contourLevels = [ 0 quantile( V_E(:), 10 ) ];
hc.LevelList = contourLevels;
```

from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/281952/plotting-electrical-field-lines-on-a-2d-plane), but I get the following error:

> `error: invalid assignment to cs-list outside multiple assignment`

What am I doing wrong?

I'm running Octave-4.2.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V_E seems to have an exponential growth; as such, your best bet to get a 'linear' looking contour image is to plot its logarithm.

I would say that this is a more sensible plot anyway. But if you *must* report the original magnitudes rather than their logarithms, you could simply then change the 'ticklabels' on the colorbar to reflect the values you want, e.g..

```
contourf(X,Y, log(V_E));
ylabel( cb = colorbar, 'Electric Potenial (V)' ) # note added 'cb' step
set(cb, 'yticklabel', exp(get(cb, 'ytick')))
```

[image]